# play framework chagne default port with dist to another port

Tags: playframework-2.2

I use playframe 2.2.1

I created a package with dist and am trying to change the default port 9000 for it to run with another port e.g. 8000

I tried the official solution bin/project -Dhttp.port=8000, but it doesnt work.It doesn't start with any port after i added this option. Not with 9000 or 8000. There is error message at all. By the way, i used play universal:package-zip-tarball to create tar package.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? It ignores your port and starts on 9000 or does not start at all? What message do you get (if any)?

Comment: It doesn't start with any port. Not with 9000 or 8000. There is error message at all. By the way, i used play universal:package-zip-tarball to create tar package.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected, just go to `target/universal` folder, unzip created package, go to unzipped folder + `bin/` (*there should be 2 files `myProject` for Unix and `myProject.bat` for Windows*) and run your project from commandline, i.e.:

```
./myProject -Dhttp.port=8000
```

Comment: I tried many times.It just doesnt work with any port if i add -Dhttp.port option. Instead of play dist, i used play universal:package-zip-tarball. It shouldnt be the probelm.

Comment: How about another port (higher than 9000?) maybe some firewall prevents you from firing at the 8000 ?

Comment: I tried 9999,9099.Neither works. When i use 8000 in dev mode with play "run 8000" or play "start 8000". It worked fine.